# How to change session ID?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I switch to a previously saved session using `Zend\Session\SessionManager`? I know the session ID.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
$sm->start();
$sm->setId('abc');
```

`$_SESSION` will not contain the data of session 'abc'. Calling `$sm->writeClose()` after `$sm->start()` doesn't help either.

I can easily do this using standard PHP functions:

```
session_start();
session_write_close();

session_id('abc');
session_start();

//$_SESSION is populated with 'abc' data.
```

Answer (score -1):

Zend uses session namespaces for that. If you give the session a name like this

```
$sess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('abc');
```

you can access the contents via `$sess->var` and reload the session in a different PHP file just by creating the new session with the same name again.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.session.basic_usage.html

Comment: I downvoted becaause it shows ZF1 - still it's pretty identical in ZF2, so the hint is still good ;)

Comment: The question is about switching sessions, not namespacing the same session.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Namespacing provides the same functionality with way less overhead & trouble.